# Getting property value by property key in array of object where each object has different property keys

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, properties

For a given name that I'm getting from an API (for example "large_banner"), I need to import the corresponding component (in this case, "LargeBanner") in my application.

So I created an array connecting each API name to each component name:

```
componentNames: [
  { index: 'ButtonSection' },
  { large_banner: 'LargeBanner' },
  { small_banner: 'SmallBanner' }
]
```

Given "large_banner" (for example), how do I get "LargeBanner" in this array? Is there a simple way to achieve that in ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on `componentNames`, search for the array item that contains the `key` (for example `large_banner`).

Then, return the value of this property if exists:

```js
const componentNames = [
  { index: 'ButtonSection' },
  { large_banner: 'LargeBanner' },
  { small_banner: 'SmallBanner' }
];

const getComponent = name => {
  const component = componentNames.find(c => c[name]);
  return component && component[name];
}

console.log( getComponent('index') );
console.log( getComponent('large_banner') );
console.log( getComponent('small_banner') );
console.log( getComponent('invalid') );
```

If you can map the names using a `JSON` object as follows, this would be simpler:

```js
const componentNames = {
  index: 'ButtonSection',
  large_banner: 'LargeBanner',
  small_banner: 'SmallBanner'
};

const getComponent = name =>
  componentNames[name];

console.log( getComponent('index') );
console.log( getComponent('large_banner') );
console.log( getComponent('small_banner') );
console.log( getComponent('invalid') );
```